# Fluent Bit rule when using multiline log start and end tags

Tags: logging, multiline, fluent-bit

I'm trying to set up Fluent Bit to pick up logs from Kubernetes/containerd and ship them to Splunk. The logs that our applications create all start with a fixed start tag and finish with a fixed end tag ([MY_LOG_START] and [MY_LOG_END]); this is consistent across all our many services and cannot realistically be changed. Here is an example of what our logs might look like:

```
[MY_LOG_START] 2023-03-17T12:34:52 INFO This is a single line log.[MY_LOG_END]
[MY_LOG_START] 2023-03-17T12:34:56 AUDIT This is a multi line log
From: some_app
To: some_other_app
Response: 200
Body: {
  "hello": "world",
  "goodbye": "moon"
}[MY_LOG_END]
[MY_LOG_START] 2023-03-17T12:34:52 WARN This is another single line log.[MY_LOG_END]
```

I can't figure out how to do this though using regex rules for multiline parsing. Here's my parser config with a few different approaches I took and comments about each one.

```
[MULTILINE_PARSER]
    name multiline-my-log
    type regex
    flush_timeout 2000

    # rules |   state name  | regex pattern                  | next state
    # ------|---------------|--------------------------------------------
    rule      "start_state"   "/^\[MY_LOG_START\].*$/"         "cont"

    # This is the closest I got and works fine as long as the log is exactly
    # three lines long. The problem is, there's no way I can see to repeat
    # the first rule until the second one is matched.
    rule      "cont"          "/^.*$/"                         "end_state"
    rule      "end_state"     "/^.*\[MY_LOG_END\]$/"           "end_state"

    # I tried using negative lookahead, but this has the problem that a)
    # the wildcard before it seems to just swallow up the whole line and
    # make the match not work and b), the final line with the end tag
    # would not be picked up as it would not match.
    #rule      "cont"          "/^.*(?!\[MY_LOG_END\].*)$/"    "cont"

    # I also tried this approach, which did not work, it does not combine
    # any of the multiline logs.
    #rule      "cont"          "/^.*[^\[][^M][^Y][^_][^L][^O][^G][^_][^E][^N][^D][^\]].*$/"  "cont"
```

In case it's relevant, here is my main Fluent Bit config I am using:

```
[INPUT]
    Name tail
    Path /var/log/containers/*.log
    # To get this working with Kubernetes, as per the following
    # article, we essentially need two multiline detections, the second (custom)
    # one of which must therefore happen in a FILTER:
    # https://www.appsloveworld.com/springboot/100/10/can-not-get-to-work-fluentbit-multi-line-parser-in-k8s-env
    multiline.parser cri
    Tag kube.*
    Buffer_Max_Size 1MB
    Mem_Buf_Limit 10MB
    Skip_Long_Lines Off
    Read_from_Head True
    Refresh_Interval 1
[FILTER]
    name                  multiline
    match                 *
    multiline.parser      multiline-my-log
    multiline.key_content log
[OUTPUT]
    Name file
    Match kube.*
    Path /var/lib/docker/containers
    Format plain
```

Comment: is `end_state` a valid state? I am only seeing cont and state_state in the docs and do not see a reference of this anywhere else.

Comment: Yes, the first rule in the list has to be called "start_state", but after that, the rest of the rules can be called whatever you want. You give each rule a name in the "state name" column and can then reference that name in the "next state" column of any other rules that you define.

Comment: The multiline parser doesn't need to care about the end tag, sine it will capture everything until it matches the start tag again.
Removing the `end_state` rule, and changing
`rule "cont" "/^.*$/" "end_state"`
to  
`rule "cont" "/^.*$/" "cont"`  
should give the desired result I think.

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me using a variant of your negative lookahead regex idea (fluent-bit 2.2.2). Basically everything that does not look like a start, should be a continuation:

```
/^(?!\[MY_LOG_START\] ).*$/
```

Parser:

```
[MULTILINE_PARSER]
    name          multiline-my-log
    key_content   log
    type          regex
    flush_timeout 2000
    rule     "start_state"   "/^\[MY_LOG_START\] .*$/"          "cont"
    rule     "cont"          "/^(?!\[MY_LOG_START\] ).*$/"      "cont"
```

Config:

```
[SERVICE]
    Log_Level         info

[INPUT]
    Name              tail
    Tag               test
    Path              /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fluent-bit/2.2.2/etc/fluent-bit/test.log
    Read_from_Head    On
    multiline.parser  cri

[FILTER]
    Name                  multiline
    Match                 *
    multiline.parser      multiline-my-log
    multiline.key_content log

[OUTPUT]
    name  stdout
    match *
```

Sample log "test.log"

```
2024-02-02T13:00:00.000000001Z stdout F [MY_LOG_START] 2023-03-17T12:34:52 INFO This is a single line log.[MY_LOG_END]
2024-02-02T13:00:00.000000002Z stdout F [MY_LOG_START] 2023-03-17T12:34:56 AUDIT This is a multi line log
2024-02-02T13:00:00.000000003Z stdout F From: some_app
2024-02-02T13:00:00.000000004Z stdout F To: some_other_app
2024-02-02T13:00:00.000000005Z stdout F Response: 200
2024-02-02T13:00:00.000000006Z stdout F Body: {
2024-02-02T13:00:00.000000007Z stdout F   "hello": "world",
2024-02-02T13:00:00.000000008Z stdout F   "goodbye": "moon"
2024-02-02T13:00:00.000000009Z stdout F }[MY_LOG_END]
2024-02-02T13:00:00.000000010Z stdout F [MY_LOG_START] 2023-03-17T12:34:52 WARN This is another single line log.[MY_LOG_END]
```

Result:

```
[2024/02/02 19:54:51] [ info] [fluent bit] version=2.2.2, commit=, pid=33432
[2024/02/02 19:54:51] [ info] [storage] ver=1.5.1, type=memory, sync=normal, checksum=off, max_chunks_up=128
[2024/02/02 19:54:51] [ info] [cmetrics] version=0.6.6
[2024/02/02 19:54:51] [ info] [ctraces ] version=0.4.0
[2024/02/02 19:54:51] [ info] [input:tail:tail.0] initializing
[2024/02/02 19:54:51] [ info] [input:tail:tail.0] storage_strategy='memory' (memory only)
[2024/02/02 19:54:51] [ info] [input:tail:tail.0] multiline core started
[2024/02/02 19:54:51] [ info] [filter:multiline:multiline.0] created emitter: emitter_for_multiline.0
[2024/02/02 19:54:51] [ info] [input:emitter:emitter_for_multiline.0] initializing
[2024/02/02 19:54:51] [ info] [input:emitter:emitter_for_multiline.0] storage_strategy='memory' (memory only)
[2024/02/02 19:54:51] [ info] [sp] stream processor started
[2024/02/02 19:54:51] [ info] [output:stdout:stdout.0] worker #0 started
[2024/02/02 19:54:51] [ info] [filter:multiline:multiline.0] created new multiline stream for tail.0_test
[0] test: [[1706878800.000000001, {}], {"time"=>"2024-02-02T13:00:00.000000001Z", "stream"=>"stdout", "_p"=>"F", "log"=>"[MY_LOG_START] 2023-03-17T12:34:52 INFO This is a single line log.[MY_LOG_END]"}]
[1] test: [[1706878800.000000002, {}], {"time"=>"2024-02-02T13:00:00.000000002Z", "stream"=>"stdout", "_p"=>"F", "log"=>"[MY_LOG_START] 2023-03-17T12:34:56 AUDIT This is a multi line log
From: some_app
To: some_other_app
Response: 200
Body: {
  "hello": "world",
  "goodbye": "moon"
}[MY_LOG_END]"}]
[0] test: [[1706878800.000000010, {}], {"time"=>"2024-02-02T13:00:00.000000010Z", "stream"=>"stdout", "_p"=>"F", "log"=>"[MY_LOG_START] 2023-03-17T12:34:52 WARN This is another single line log.[MY_LOG_END]"}]
```

Please note that I've added CRI headers in the sample data to be able to enable **multiline.parser  cri** in the tail input configuration to make the test more realistic.